# Python anaconda spider not reflecting changes

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I don't know if is a problem of spider or just configuration. But when I modify some .py file and put save changes and run it again the changes mades are sometimes not reflected until I close spider and open it again. Why is that?

Comment: This is often seen when you run a script that imports a module you're modifying. If this is the case, then bear in mind that Python won't re-import a module just because you're running the script again; you would need to `reload` the module then (see i.e. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-to-reload-a-python-module)).